# Sort a list based on unit place, tens place, hundred place digit in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

Suppose I have a list, I want to sort the digits in the following pattern:

```
A = [3, 30, 34, 256, 5, 9]
```

Sort by unit place digit first, if unit place digit is same then we will compare `tens place` and then `hundred place`. If you sort the A by this rule then:

```
A = [9, 5, 34, 3, 30, 256]

9 is the highest digit at Unit place 
5 is second highest
3, 34, 30 since unit digit is same here, we will compare tens place so 34 will come first here, then 3 and 30.
256 will come last since its unit place digit is 2 which is the lowest.

Suppose B = [100, 10, 1]
then after sorting B = [1, 10, 100]
```

Could anyone share some Pythonic way to solve this issue?

I have tried `sorted(nums, key=lambda x: int(x[0]), reverse=True)` but here how will I take `tenth place digit` into account?

Update: There is one point missing suppose `A = [1, 100, 10]` then in such cases after sorting `A = [1, 10, 100]`. In the example I gave `A = [3, 30, 34, 256, 5, 9]` here after sorting `A = [9, 5, 34, 3, 30, 256]`.

> Overall logic is I want to join all digits and create a largest
>   number.

Comment: Units is the *rightmost* position. The numeral in the units position of 256 is **6**.

Comment: Oh shit!! I am so tired. Let me rephrase the question again :/

Comment: I mean to ask from sort from `leftmost to rightmost` position.

Comment: [34, 3, 30] is a very odd choice.

Comment: Main idea is if you combine all these digits it will generate the largest number possible. `34330 > 34303`

Comment: @python I think that's asking a different question. I suggest you ask a new question with that specific problem, then we can see if there are other solutions. (that's a neat problem)

Comment: Okay. I am sorry for this confusion

Answer (score 5):

I think you just want str as the key:

```
In [11]: sorted(A, key=str, reverse=True)
Out[11]: [9, 5, 34, 30, 3, 256]
```

Initially I read your question that you would want the reversed digits:

```
In [12]: sorted(A, key=lambda x: str(x)[::-1])
Out[12]: [30, 3, 34, 5, 256, 9]
```

Comment: if there are three numbers like `A = [3, 30, 300]` then 3 should come first from `30` and `30` should come first before `300`.

Comment: I think you want `sorted(A, key=lambda x: str(x) + "a", reverse=True)`, but it's a little unclear from your examples.

Comment: Main idea is if you combine all these digits it should generate a largest number. So if you combine `A = [9, 5, 34, 3, 30, 256]` 9534330256 is the largest number you can get.

Answer (score 3):

The following code answers the updated question: "sort in a way that concatenated sorted numbers will give the highest possible number".
The idea is if most significant digits are same and length is different the longer number is "greater" than the shorter number if in longer number the (shorter number length + 1) digit is greater or equal than the most significant digit. Eg: 30 < 3, 32 < 3, 35 > 3, 10 < 1, 3003 > 3, 3001 < 3, 345 > 34, 342 < 34.

```
>>> def f(x, y):
...     if x == y:
...         return 0
...     xs = str(x)
...     ys = str(y)
...     for i in range(min(len(xs), len(ys))):
...         if xs[i] > ys[i]:
...             return 1
...         elif xs[i] < ys[i]:
...             return -1
...     if len(xs) > len(ys):
...         return 1 if xs[0] <= xs[len(ys)] else -1
...     return -1 if ys[0] <= ys[len(xs)] else 1
...
>>> A = [3, 30, 34, 256, 5, 9]
>>> B = [100,10,1]
>>> sorted(A, cmp=f, reverse=True)
[9, 5, 34, 3, 30, 256]
>>> sorted(B, cmp=f, reverse=True)
[1, 10, 100]
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, you did really want a numbers-as-text string sort.  Well if you wanted the units -> tens -> hundreds sort you described, this does it:

```
# Repeatedly modulo 10 to get the rightmost digit
# (units, then tens, then hundreds) until the 
# digit where the two numbers differ. Compare those two digits.
>>> def f(x, y):
...     xr = x % 10
...     yr = y % 10
...     while x and y and xr == yr:
...         x, xr = divmod(x, 10)
...         y, yr = divmod(y, 10)
...     return cmp(xr, yr)
... 
>>> A = [3, 30, 34, 256, 5, 9]
>>> sorted(A, cmp=f)
[30, 3, 34, 5, 256, 9]
```

It's not sorting as your example output, but it is sorting by units - 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9. And if it had any where the units were the same, it sorts by tens, etc.

```
>>> A = [3, 30, 34, 266, 256, 5, 9]
>>> sorted(A, cmp=f)
[30, 3, 34, 5, 256, 266, 9]
```

Comment: cmp is not available in python 3. :(

Comment: @AndyHayden Shameful. It's probably replaced with some awful-to-use-in-the-repl thing like everything else, eh? Lucky the question is tagged Python-2.7. (Not that I noticed earlier).

Answer (score 0):

This is a different version from other previously posted answers:

```
import itertools

def produce_list(A):
   At = [str(x) for x in A]  # convert the items to str so we can join them
   result = 0
   for i in itertools.permutations(At):  # go through all permutations
      temp = int(''.join(i))
      if result < temp:   # find the biggest value of the combined numbers
          result = temp
          result_list = list(i)

   return [int(x) for x in result_list]  # return the list of ints

print produce_list([3, 30, 34, 256, 5, 9])
print produce_list([100, 1, 10])
```

It might not be very efficient (it will go through every combination) but it is as Pythonic as I could get.